# Create unknow amount of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, object

I have the following situation, what I want to know is how I go about creating the objects (since I have no idea how many there will be):

```
jQuery.each($itemList, function() {
    <something> = new ItemObject(this[1], this[2]);
});
```

Can ***something*** be an array? If so, do I use .push? or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: What will you be using <something> for ?

Comment: Something can be an Array, it's probably the best way to do it.

Comment: Every object (something) refers to a picture on the webpage (there are an unknown amount of pictures on the page). Every 10 seconds I need to change attributes on all images. It is a bit complex to explain what and why because each image has it's own unique bahaviour depending on a number which is retrieved via PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its probably the most convinient way to push those newly created objects into an Array.

```
var objectList = [ ];

jQuery.each($itemList, function() {
   objectList.push( new ItemObject(this[1], this[2]) );
});

// somewhere else
objectList.forEach(function( obj ) {
    // do something great
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't sure this was the best way of doing this.